# How to give multiple colours for a plot with Coreplot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I want to draw a plot colour should be varied with certain ranges as shown in image.

The plot below the line should be drawn with **Green Colour** and plot above the line should be drawn with **Red Colour**.

Please suggest if any method available for giving separate colours for `plotSymbol` and `plot.lineStyle` in various ranges of plot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method to draw a different symbol at each plot point on a scatter plot. You'll get better drawing performance if you use the same symbol object for all points that should have the same symbol rather than creating a new one for each point. For your case, create two symbols, one red and one green, and return the correct one at each index depending on the y-value.

There is no way to draw part of the plot line in one color and part in another color. You can use two plots, one with each desired line style, and have each one only display the points above or below the cutoff value. Return `nil` or `[NSNull null]` from the datasource for the points on the other side of the cutoff to leave gaps in the line.